# Soundcloud API allow granular track play data retrieval?

Tags: api, soundcloud

Does the SoundCloud API all one to retrieve data on all plays (date of play, which track, app/rss/logged in user) for a particular (or all tracks) that I created?

From reading through the API reference it appears the only play data is an aggregated number for each track. I want to slice and dice my data by those parameters above.

Marc